# How to count string frequency in array ( cypher, neo4j )

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have an array of strings and I want to count how many times one string is found in the array.

For example:

```
["Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix", "Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix", "Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix", "Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix", "Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix", "Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix", "Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix", "Gone with the Wind", "Gone with the Wind", "Gone with the Wind", "Gone with the Wind",""Shopaholic to the Stars (Shopaholic, #7)"", "The Farm", "The Farm", "Men Explain Things to Me", "The Valley of Fear", " The Fellowship of the Ring", " The Fellowship of the Ring", " The Fellowship of the Ring", " The Fellowship of the Ring", " The Fellowship of the Ring", "Mastering the Art of French Cooking", "Play With Me", "Play With Me", "Play With Me", "The Perfect Play", "The Perfect Play", "The Perfect Play", "Dream a Little Dream", "Natural Born Charmer", "Collected Poems", "The Friend Zone"]
```

I want to return the name of the book and how many times appears in the array.

For example:

- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix - 5
- The Fellowship of the Ring - 1

etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UNWIND and then aggregate by using count:

```
UNWIND ["Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix", "Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix", "Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix", "Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix", "Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix", "Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix", "Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix", "Gone with the Wind", "Gone with the Wind", "Gone with the Wind", "Gone with the Wind","Shopaholic to the Stars (Shopaholic, #7)", "The Farm", "The Farm", "Men Explain Things to Me", "The Valley of Fear", " The Fellowship of the Ring", " The Fellowship of the Ring", " The Fellowship of the Ring", " The Fellowship of the Ring", " The Fellowship of the Ring", "Mastering the Art of French Cooking", "Play With Me", "Play With Me", "Play With Me", "The Perfect Play", "The Perfect Play", "The Perfect Play", "Dream a Little Dream", "Natural Born Charmer", "Collected Poems", "The Friend Zone"]  as book

RETURN book, count(*) as book_cnt
```

Answer (score 1):

The [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/index32.html) library offers [collection helper functions](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/index32.html#_collection_functions) that can be useful here, notably `apoc.coll.occurrences()`:

Assuming you're passing in parameters, and $bookToFind is the string of the book you're looking for, and $bookList is the list of books (though this would probably be from your graph somewhere) you could use:

```
RETURN apoc.coll.occurrences($bookList, $bookToFind) as occurrences
```

Alternately, if you want to get the frequency of all books, and not just a certain one, you can use `apoc.coll.frequencies()` on the collection, which gives you back a list of maps, each map consisting of an `item` and a `count` of that item in the list.